# Convert what is typed into UITextField to a counter number like 00:01

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` where the Keyboard Type is a number pad. I want to be able to type numbers so they are formatted as a time such as: `00:00`

**For Example**
Typing 1 -> `00:01`
Typing 1, 2 -> `00:12`
Typing 1, 2, 3 -> `01:23`
Typing 1, 2, 3, 4 -> `12:34`

`12:34` symbolizes `12 minutes and 32 seconds`

Also, once you reach the max 4 digits typing more will do nothing.

I would also like to convert whatever was typed, such as `01:23` to an `Int` of seconds - e.g. `83` in this case - if possible.

Comment: What did you try? Please show some code...

Comment: I tried this but many errors and not exactly what I want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34239761/7842955

Comment: Its just logic. Read Least significant as two Second as seconds and most significant digits as hour. Keep it as a string and make method to convert it into num of seconds

Comment: What if the user wants to type 19 minutes and zero seconds. What would it display when the user types the first zero `01:90` ??

Comment: @LeoDabus If the user types a zero, then a zero will be displayed and the cursor will go to the next character in line. So you can then type a 1 and it will say `00:10`

Comment: @Loctor I recommend using a UIPickerView as your textfield input view

Answer (score 0):

You back the textfield with an Int and modify the Int when the user pushes a key.  You then display the formatted Int as the text.  Here is an example playground:

```
import PlaygroundSupport

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var textField =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))
    var number = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.backgroundColor = .white
        textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        textField.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(textField)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        switch string {
        case "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9":
            guard number < Int32.max / 100 else {
                return false
            }
            number *= 10
            number += Int(string)!
        case "":
            number /= 10
        default:
            break
        }

        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.decimalSeparator = ":"
        formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        textField.text = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Double(number) / 100.0))
        return false
    }
}

let v = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = v.view
```

Comment: You can use Formatter's method `string(for: Any)` instead of NumberFormatter method `string(from: NSNumber)` and pass any numeric type, in your case `Double`. ie.: `formatter.string(for:  Double(number) / 100)`